Does "A invasion" and "A's invasion" have the opposite meanings?
Since Russia invaded Ukraine, saying "Russia's invasion of Ukraine" or "the Russian invasion" presents no problem. Yet occasionally, I see people also refer to it as "Ukraine invasion", e.g. in the following links:

https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/7276/text
https://fortune.com/tag/ukraine-invasion/
https://www.arcgis.com/apps/mapviewer/index.html?webmap=9f04944a2fe84edab9da31750c2b15eb
https://theconversation.com/us/topics/ukraine-invasion-2022-117045
https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-invasion-predictions-wrong-intelligence/32275740.html

Hence, is it true that "A invasion" means A is invaded by others and "A's invasion" means A invades others?

There's a difference between "Russia [noun] invasion," "Russia's [possessive] invasion," and "Russian [adjective] invasion." I don't think you really meant to write "Russian's [possessive from singular demonym] invasion." Note that most of the examples you give are headlines, titles, or headings

Prenominal adjectives, and noun modifiers, have many different semantic relationships with the nouns they modify. This can lead to ambiguities (think of 'a criminal lawyer'), but context (in nearby words/sentences, or afforded by reasonably expected knowledge) almost always disambiguates. An invasion involves two states (obviously not in a symmetric situation).

It's not math, it's whatever makes sense. Canned tuna contains tuna, pitted olives contain no pits, baby formula does not contain babies.
Consider hand job, handy wipes, hand lotion.

Aah, criminal lawyer! But @EdwinAshworth, "many different," as opposed to many of the same? Crestfallen, I tell you.

@Yosef Baskin
The comma forces the sense: Prenominal adjectives have many different semantic relationships with the nouns they modify. So do attributive nouns. (I used to have a list of about 14; eg N₁N₂ = N₂ is constructed of N₁ // N₁N₂ = N₂ performs N₁ //

I meant that "many different" seems repetitious.

@YosefBaskin "Many different" is opposed to just 2-3 different.

Wikipedia uses the unambigous Russian invasion of Ukraine, German invasion of the Netherlands, French invasion of Russia, Anglo-Soviet invasion of Iran; or French invasions in Brazil, which describes a looser series of attacks that preceded the establishment of the state of Brazil.

Thanks for all the comments!
